# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, signals, segmentation-fault

Why am I getting segmentation fault when I am passing a string called `name` with contents `joel` into:

```
void person::setName(string newName)
{
    personName = newName;
}
```

Header file:

```
class person {
public:
    int getID();
    string getName();

    void setID(int newID);
    void setName(string newName);
private:
    int personID;
    string personName;

};
```

The function call is by a child, although I dont see how that could cause an issue.

Comment: Also... It runs on previous itterations without fault... It just doesnt like this iteration... I would link the code but theres buckets of the stuff X(

Comment: I don't think your problem is that function.  You may want to take a look at how you are creating/accessing the person object you are using.

Comment: Your code example is alright, the segfault is caused somewhere else. Please step through your code with a debugger to find the line of code causing the error.

Comment: @falconmick: Then please reduce your code to the *minimum* possible and post it here.  There's no issue with the above code, in isolation, at least.

Comment: also the varible personName equaled (in my watches) "the program being debugged was signaled while in a function call from gdb"

Comment: Um, are you saying that that string "the program being debugged..." was the contents of that variable? Very strange. Can you tell us which line of code the fault is on? Build the program with -g (if using GCC), then run it in GDB. It will break on the error. If you don't recognise where you are, then type `bt` which will show the function call stack. Look up the stack until you find some of your code -- that is the line with the error.

Comment: @mgiuca: To be precise, that would be the line with the *symptom*.  The actual error could be elsewhere.

Comment: @mgiuca: gdb is just confirming that the this pointer is invalid at the time of evaluation. +1 for using a debugger, btw

Comment: @Oli Chalesworth / @sehe indeed. I was trying to simplify things but perhaps I over-simplified. To show that I know what I'm on about ;) I wrote a guide to debugging these issues: http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~mgiuca/253/bad.html Perhaps it will be helpful.

Comment: @mguica: Ha - nice find (bgcc, formerly not known to me). However, like debugging STL iterators and debugging heap allocators, they all pale in comparison to the sheer fundamentalism of valgrind; it does positively check for **any unitialized/undefined** memory references, be it within or out of bounds (in addition to doing the leak checking) - all without even requiring debug builds or any specific compiler. That rocks

Comment: Read [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Then load your core dump into the debugger and see what's going on.

Answer (score 23):

If you are on Linux, try running [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). You just compile with `-g` (with gcc), and then run your program with `valgrind` in front:

```
$ valgrind myprogram
```

Unlike the GCC solutions, which tell you when the segfault occurs, valgrind usually tells you exactly when the first memory corruption occurs, so you can catch the problem much closer to its source.

PS. It rhymes with "flint", not "find".

Comment: +1 for giving the right pronunciation of valgrind ('valgreend')

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you are dereferencing a rogue pointer. By pure guesswork, have you got something like this, perhaps:

```
 Person persons[10];

 for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
     persons[i].setName("joel");
```

The problem might be:

- the error like shown, the index is 0-based, so you need `for (i=0; i<10; i++)`
- if the array is allocated dynamically, but the index is still out of bounds

There could literally be hundreds of other causes, but since I don't have your code, this is my attempt to guess most plausible errors ;)

(*Note to self: why am I doing this/I'm not psychic?*)

Comment: Would you add information of "allocated dynamically"? Do you mean this, https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/?

Comment: @CloudCho Not really (but yes, `new`/`delete` is by definition dynamic allocation. Don't use it, though,  in modern c++). It's easier to say "not automatic storage duration" - which means stack variable of global statics. The classic example is heap allocation. Which in c++ is usually done through other classes (like std::vector or std::string etc) but you can also directly do it using make_unique or make_shared. They have the benefit over `new/delete` that they promote exception-aware code without leaks  and most other pitfalls surrounding dynamic allocation in C++

Comment: you mentioned the `make_shared` function template. I had a hard time to using it. Here is my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695290/drawback-of-declaring-and-defining-variable-at-return) Do you mostly stand with the suggestions in there?

Comment: @CloudCho Yes. A word of advice: instead of debating every claim you see people make, use patience and judgement. Just monitor answers (or contribute them) for a longer period of time and sharpen your judgement over time :) Kudos for "aggressive-learning" though. I admire that trait and it will definitely help your learning path.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class person {
public:
    int getID();
    string getName();

    void setID(int newID);
    void setName(string newName);
private:
    int personID;
    string personName;

};

void person::setName(string newName)
{
    personName = newName;
    cout << personName << endl;
}

int main() {
  person* obj = new person();
  obj->setName("your name");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add at least some comments to your code to explain what it does and how it's supposed to answer the question.